# React props are updating even when i'm not using the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I made a project using the create-react-app template. I am trying to import data from a JSON file and send it to the todos component file as props but I'm not using it as a prop in the Todos file but when I update the file using add button in-app component, it updates the todo list. I don't understand why it is doing that. It will be a great help if someone can explain what's going on.

This is the app.js file

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import Todos from "./todos";
import tasks from './data.json';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { task: '' };
    this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  addTask() {
    tasks.push({
      title: this.state.task,
      done: false
    });
    this.setState({ task: "" });
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ task: event.target.value });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <input className="App-task-input" type="text" placeholder="Title"
            value={this.state.task} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <button className="App-add-btn" onClick={this.addTask}>Add Task</button>
        </header>
        <Todos tasks={tasks} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

This is todos.js file

```
import { Component } from "react";
import tasks from "./data.json";

class Todos extends Component {
  changeCheckbox(index) {
    console.log(index, tasks);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <main className="todo">
        // It should update if i use this.props.tasks instead of tasks
        {tasks.map((t, i) =>
          <div className="todo-item" key={i}>
            <input
              id={t.id}
              className="todo-checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              checked={t.done}
              onChange={this.changeCheckbox.bind(this, i)} />
            <label className="todo-label" htmlFor={t.id}>{t.title}</label>
          </div>
        )}
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default Todos;
```

Comment: `addTask() { tasks.push({ title: this.state.task, done: false}); this.setState({ task: "" }); }` here you are updating the tasks and setting state therefore it's rerendering child component

Comment: once you update state in parent component it will rerender child too.

Comment: if you want to handle this use `Pure component` or `shouldComponentUpdate` in `class component` and `memo` in `functional component`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever state change component re-renders and here you have parent and child component.

In your parent component you are updating your lists that's why child also getting re-render whether you are passing changes or not. I will happen.

To prevent this, you need to use **`shouldComponentUpdate`**, **`React.memo`** or **`PureComponent`**.

For your reference to understand scenario and with example.

> Whenever you call method **`setState()`**, component automatically re-renders

[How to prevent unnecassery re-rendering](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-prevent-rerender-component/)